# Scope variable is also updating non scope variable on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a user settings page in Angular that will be used to update the users profile settings. This is how I've done it (pardon my use of jquery please)

```
$scope.userObj = {};
var userObjTemp = {};
$http.get('/api/to/get/user').success(function(data) {
    if (data.success != true) {
        $state.go('index');
    } else {
        $scope.userObj.user = data.response; //scope variable to show in html form
        userObjTemp.user = data.response; //temp data in case someone cancels editing
        var tempDob = $scope.userObj.user.dob;
        $scope.userObj.user.dob = tempDob.split('-')[2] + '/' + tempDob.split('-')[1] + '/' + tempDob.split('-')[0];
        console.log({
            userObjData: $scope.userObj
        });
        console.log({
            tempData: userObjTemp
        });
    }
});
$scope.showSetting = function(target) {
    $('.setting-edit-row').hide();
    $('.jr-input-setting').show();
    $('#' + target + '-input').hide();
    $('#' + target).show();
}
$scope.saveSetting = function(key) {
    var postDict = {};
    postDict[key] = $scope.userObj.user[key];
    $http.put('/api/user', postDict).success(function(data) {
        $scope.userObj.user = data.response;
        $('.setting-edit-row').hide();
        $('.jr-input-setting').show();
    })
}
$scope.shutSetting = function(target) {
    $scope.userObj.user = {};
    $scope.userObj.user = userObjTemp.user;
    $('#' + target).hide();
    $('#' + target + '-input').show();
}
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="row setting-fixed-row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="setting-label">
            Name
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="jr-input-setting" id="setting-name-input" disabled="true" ng-model="userObj.user.display_name" type="text" placeholder="Display Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="edit-btn" ng-click="showSetting('setting-name')">
            Edit
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 setting-edit-row" id="setting-name">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove shut-det" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-click="shutSetting('setting-name')"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
                <input class="jr-input-edit" ng-model="userObj.user.display_name" placeholder="Display Name" id="display_name" ng-change="showVal()">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="save-settings" ng-click="saveSetting('display_name')">
                    Save
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea behind `shutSetting()` is to shut the editing panel `setting-edit-row` and restore the original data that I got from the `api`. However, when I do this, it shows me the temp variable being the same as the `$scope.userObj` variable. I added a `$scope.showVal` function to show the variables on change of the input form:

```
$scope.showVal = function(){
    console.log({userObj: $scope.userObj});
    console.log({temp: userObjTemp});
}
```

For some reason, both variables are getting updated. How do I fix this as I've never faced something similar before.

Comment: well you assign to that variable  userObjTemp.user = data.response; //temp data in case someone cancels editing so its there?

Comment: try with `userObjTemp.user = angular.copy(data.response)`

Comment: So the idea is to keep two copies of the data response. One that remains constance regardless of editing and one that is used for editing.  Shouldn't userObjTemp not be equal to userObj on change of userObj?

Comment: @EsseTi, that worked. You can add that as an answer below. How exactly does this help though?

Comment: they are referenced not copied. so if you update the `userObj` also the `userObjTemp` is also updated. thus, use the `copy` instead of plain assigment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are *referencing* objects instead of *copying* them. Thus

```
$scope.userObj.user = data.response;
userObjTemp.user = data.response;
```

points all to the same object. Then, when you update one of the two also the other gets updated.

```
userObjTemp.user = angular.copy(data.response)
```

this makes a copy.

Just in case: https://jsfiddle.net/qzj0w2Lb/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that both of your variables are referencing the same object `data.response`. Depending on the object, you could use `$.extend(true, {}, data.response);` to get a clone of the object.

Be aware though, that this is not a true "deep copy" when custom objects are involved!